# How to install from virtualenv only?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, requirements.txt

I'm confused about `virtualenv`. I've been reading docs and trying examples, but its not getting better.

I created a `virtualenv` in the following way:

```
$ virtualenv myapp_venv --no-site-package
```

I used `--no-site-packages` because I want to know that that my `requirements.txt` is sufficient for building and running my code. I don't want to depend on whatever may be installed on my dev machine.

Then I try to install dependencies into my `virtualenv`:

```
$ source myapp_venv/bin/activate
(myapp_venv) $ sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

At this point I get a number of messages like this:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask==0.10.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

This surprises me, as I thought `virtualenv` would not be concerned with globally available packages, but with the environment of this project.

When I proceed to try to run the application:

```
(myapp_venv) $ python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/eric/code/python/tournament/app/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

But if I deactivate the `virtualenv`, the app runs just fine.

How can I git `pip` to install the packages into the `virtualenv`?

For context, I'm professionally experienced with Java/Maven. I have a bit of Python language experience, but the Python ecosystem is still new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the sudo, and you will be fine.
Sudo is telling to install globally.

Comment: Wow, I've never known `sudo` to have that effect. Very surprising.

Comment: When you use sudo you are acting as root. When you act as root pip will install at a global level.Since flask is already installed your system globally, it will give you that requirement already satisfied. But when you run in virtualenv locally with no-site-packages, it will not find it since that option isolates the virtualenv from the global modules.Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Check `no-global-site-packages.txt` in your `lib`.

If `no-global-site-packages.txt` file is in `lib` folder, then It will take all packages from your `virtualenv` else It will take globally.

Also, As wissam said, don't use `sudo`. It is correct. because using `sudo`, It will install globally.